# Yahoopipes Picasa feed <media:thumbnail> accessing at runtime results

Tags: javascript, yahoo-pipes

I am using YahooPipes code to parse a cross domain picasa feed in its minimal form. I would like to know how to read the media:group - media:thumbnail tag in the xml retrieved at Runtime.

```
for (var i=0; i<feed.value.items.length; i++){tmp+='<a href="'+feed.value.items[i].link+'">';tmp+=feed.value.items[i].title+'</a><br>';if (feed.value.items[i].description) {tmp=feed.value.items[i].description;}
```

How will I retrieve at runtime I mean to say

```
tmp+=feed.value.items[i]......media:group.media:thumbnail[0].url
```

here...

The sample feed is here:

http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/user/mdalthaf786/albumid/5481762720476791505?alt=rss&kind=photo&hl=en_US&fields=item(media:group(media:thumbnail))&thumbsize=288&go.xml

Answer (score 0):

Okay!

I found out that myself...May be It will help someone, looking for it in near future.

```
tmp+=feed.value.items[i]['media:group']['media:thumbnail'][0].url;
```

You know you can call CrossDomain calls to data /  xml using YahooPipes. Even on Hosts that do not allow (mostly Free Hosts), cross domain calls in Server Sides.